# Assign/add mixin or sub-component at runtime?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Can I dynamically add a mixin? I think I read that runtime insertion of mixins is not supported and will never be. Is the below runtime insertion possible?

My usecase is; all our pages are stored in a database, each page standard properties like; title, content and template. We have components for each template. Each template component displays the title and content differently. So I need to build the routes and say this page uses this (template) component. Maybe I can use sub-components to achieve this? Can I dynamically add sub-components at runtime?

The easiest solution is to do the following:

Router:

```
// myPages retrieved by REST call
const routes = _.map(myPages, page => {
    return {
        path: `/${page.url}`,
        name: page.name,
        component: DefaultPage  // make all pages use DefaultPage component
    }
});
```

DefaultPage.vue

```
<template>

</template>

<script>
import mixins from './mixins';

export default {

  mixins: [mixins.Base]

  beforeMount() {
    // I dont think this is possible?
    let templateMixin = mixins[ this.page.template ]
    this.mixins.push( templateMixin );
  }

}
</script>
```

Maybe its possible to assign a sub-component at runtime?

```
<template>
    // Somehow call the sub-component (template)?
    <template></template>
</template>

<script>
import templates from './templates';

export default {

  components: {},

  beforeMount() {
    // Is this possible?

    let templateCmp = templates[ this.page.template ]
    this.components = {
      templateCmp
    }
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: you mean [async component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is a lot of misinformation on the web stating that "because of userland perils, it's not safe or secure to load dynamic or "runtime" components", and that doing so is "a security risk".

This stems from the reasoning that Vue uses the `eval` statement when compiling components.  However, so does React and Angular. There is in fact no way to compile components without this. while eval is a sharp knife, so is any JavaScript. Saying that a sharp knife is insecure is false as long as you keep that sharp knife itself secure.

The notion that runtime components is insecure is utterly and completely false.  There are tons of officially supported ways to do this if you control the source.  In fact, there is even an officially Vue supported "userland" method to load dynamic/async components even if you **don't** control the source(!!)

**Async components**

Probably the easiest way to load a page from a database (which itself may have it's own sub-components, mixins and dependencies), is with [async components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components).

This is an official part of Vue and I've used it in dozens of production apps. It works exactly like expected; nothing is invoked by your application until all the conditions are met, and when the load conditions are met, you are free to obtain the component however you see fit.

**Note:** You *must* control the source of these components, or XSS injection and other hacking is possible.

If you're using webpack, it's easy to get all the components dependencies into a single file. In the above URL are specific how-to articles including a video tutorial of how to produce a single js file for your pages dependencies that aren't part of your main application.

One caveat for loading multiple sub components this way is you may overlap/repeat loading (i.e. page A may load 5 sub components that no other static page loads, and page B may load 5 sub components, 3 of which are shared with page A, and 2 of which are specific to page B).  Caveats like these can mess up your optimization techniques if you don't think them through. This can be unavoidable and fine, and still much faster than loading the entire app at once though.

**Async components in userland**

If you only want to load custom templates from a database (i.e. if you don't want to allow users to load their own custom components, mixins, filters, directives, etc), with each template, then you are in luck; Vue even has official support for async templates that are locked-down to only allowing template changes. This is enough to offer your component builders scaffolding for creating an app, but prevents them from executing arbitrary JavaScript code (this method won't let them setup a data section, or hook into the component lifecycle for example).

[v-runtime-template](https://github.com/alexjoverm/v-runtime-template) is officially recognized by the Vue.js team as the official method for creating userland-safe Vue templates.

I've used v-runtime-template in platforms used by some of the biggest names in the industry across tens of millions of users without a single security breach, because this method only exposes the components you say are OK.

**Further template lockdown using JSON schemas**

If you need only form generation, or you can simplify your components further, and you only need to reason about data in simple ways like queries (i.e. if you're building a survey generator, or an analytics or other widget dashboard), you can build components out of JSON Schemas using [vue-form-json-schema](https://github.com/jarvelov/vue-form-json-schema). This method takes 2 schemas: one for your data, and one for your form.  The parent component you load specifies all the components that are accessible to the schema, so you must whitelist components that userland has access to, further, the forms cannot run arbitrary JavaScript, they can only call functions that you make available in the parent component, which are your JavaScript whitelist.

**Userland-Safe Queries on arbitrary data**

You can let users query specific JSON objects for use in completely-safe userland queries that can be provided by the public using [JSONata](https://jsonata.org/). Developed by IBM, JSONata is a way to safely query and, with the exposure of a few functions, allows your users to even manipulate data in verified-safe ways.

Although JSONata is logically proven to be safe in unserland, it is also Turing-complete without functions, meaning your users can manipulate the Schema provided data by outputting new data that can technically do anything; i.e. your users can create Doom 3 using JSONata queries.  People have made games like Pong and other interesting things out of JSONata.

JSONata's power cannot be overstated. It powers the magic behind nearly all no-code/low-code platforms like the open source [Node-RED](https://nodered.org/), and is behind many other proprietary no-code/low-code platforms that are closed source, including Google, Microsoft, Amazon and IBM platforms.

They use JSONata to translate data schemas between platforms, and whenever business logic is needed on data manipulation, and the manipulation must be left in user-land (i.e. an app that needs to manipulate data, but you want to run that app on your platform and not have to worry about QA or people being able to hack or write a nefarious app that breaks into your platform).